# Remove specific things from string in Python

Tags: python, string

I am struggling to remove some characters in a string. This is inside a loop. So if the string contains either of the below, then it needs to remove them and leave the rest behind.

Characters to remove:
"-"
"1)", "2)" etc

Here is the loop:

```
for i in item:
    if i != "":
        items[heading].append(i)
```

I am just wondering if there is any advice as to where I can look for help please :)

Here is what I have tried, without the desired results:

```
for i in item:
    if i != "":
        i = i.replace('-', '')
        i = i[i.find(')'):]
        items[title].append(i)
```

Comment: What is `item`?

Comment: @mousetail item is a list of stings. For example: `['item', '-item', '1) item', '2)']`

Comment: You could use the `.replace()` function or use `re.sub()` for more control

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this!

```py
bl = ["-", "1)", "2)"]
string = "-2)Hello1) World!"

for item in bl:
  string = string.replace(item, "")

print(string)
```

Comment: Just add any string or character you want to `bl` and it will then remove it from the string.